# Given center coordinates and radius how can i find two other coordinates NE and SW

Tags: trigonometry

I wanted to find two coordinates which are NE and SW coordinates of a circle on a map with center (xr,yr) and a radius 100m.
I tried NE=(x=rcos(45), ysin(45)) and SW=(x=rcos(315), ysin(315)), assuming 0degrees is north, but it seems it is not correct.
How do i go about the solution

Comment: SW can't be $270^\circ$, right?

Comment: How do i get the angle of SW and NE

Comment: $NE: (x=rcos(45°), rsin(45°))$ is right, why do you think it is wrong.( I suppose the   ysin45 is just a typo)

Comment: Apart from the SW angle, if you follow the $(x,y) = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ formula, then you would be choosing north as the positive $x$ direction, and east as the positive $y$ direction.

Comment: will it be correct if the center of the circle changes

Comment: @RonaldSaunfe no, you have to offset the northward and eastward distances of the point on the circle, by the centre of the circle.

Comment: should it be NE=(xr +X=rcos(45), yr+Y=rsin(45))

Comment: You can check with real numbers to see if the answer makes sense, for example what if the centre of the circle is at $(x,y)=(200, 100)$, and the radius is $5$?

Comment: center=(-3.4215852, 38.5074926)
NE=(3000.3244020013644, 4903.900721364449)
SW=(-3816.787675198299, -4222.100479249363) distance = 5717.914 m after adding offset above, still not correct